# Solution for database version control and deployment?

Tags: database, migration, version-control

Currently i use a dump script and commit the database to the git repo. 
`--skip-extended-insert --skip-comments --skip-dump-date` means that a diff can give me a fair idea of what has changed, but it all falls down if I try to merge.

The WP_SITEURL, WP_HOME and all the other places wordpress stores full URLs need updating when importing to another host (testing,staging,production)

Is anyone using a better method?

**Main issues:**

- Wordpress stores full URLs all through the database (non-portable)
- Lots of other, non-relevant records change

  - auto_increment values (i just strip these out, but have run into ID issues)
  - timestamps (can also strip out, potentially)
  - *transient** records ... no idea what to do with them

A process that created timestamped migrations, with only the things added or removed, would be ideal... but i'm not sure if it's even possible?

Comment: Do you want to version **all data changes** or *only changes in structure*? and that is your real BUSINESS-TASK?

Comment: When making changes to CMS's like wordpress, there are often content and configuration (DB data) changes along with logic (code) changes. I would like to be able to version both. Structure changes would be a good start ...

BUSINESS TASK: client asks for new widget. Install plugin on staging server, commit to repo -> Configure plugin and add sample content -> once approved, pull code changes to production, then manually make same data changes in production admin.

Comment: @JacobDorman I'm trying to solve this exact same problem. Have you worked something out yet?

After some research I'm starting to think some custom plugin that creates a specific update script is in order (probably to export only configuration changes such as installed plugins, and configuration options -- and not necessarily posts, categories, and content in general). 

Would love to hear if you have any other ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions, both of these are actually generic MySQL version control tools but can be adapted to your workflow:

[dbv.php](https://github.com/victorstanciu/dbv)

This tool creates "migrations", which are basically SQL scripts, from the changes detected on the database. These scripts are stored in a local directory and thus can be commited to your current VCS (git, for example).

It's used through a PHP web interface.

[DBVC](https://github.com/jasny/dbvc)

Fundamentally similar to the previous tool, this is based on a command line interface. It's configured through a json file. The main difference is that it doesn't auto-generate the migration files.

There's a pending issue to integrate this with the previous similar, so that's something to look for.

**Wordpress Plugins**

Some plugins that could aid in the creation of a repeatable workflow:

- [VersionPress (still in early development at this date)](http://versionpress.net/)
- [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) (there is a [pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/) version)
- [WP Synch DB](https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db) (a fork of the previous project with some of the pro features included)

Comment: dbvc looks like the kind of tool I've been looking for. thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I just found another interesting tool,it hasn't been updated in a while, but it might be worth to take a loot at: https://github.com/idler/MMP

Comment: @JacobDorman With DBVC, are you able to successfully merge DB changes from different environments? I have built [a strategy of my own](https://github.com/enderandpeter/wpgithooks/tree/wpaddons), but does DBVC produce the update files or do you have to use something like [mysqldiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldiff.html) between SQL dumps? I can't image this tool being useful unless it helps produce SQL differences that are actually comparable, especially INSERT statement parameters on separate lines... although I suppose a file could be edited  to deal with that...

Comment: @SpencerWilliams I didn't end up using DBVC (and haven't used mysqldiff) but still add db dumps to version control... I don't really see them as mergeable in most cases, but diffing using beyond compare can help highlight changes and issues.

Comment: @victor I checked out MMP. It does schema changes, but not data diffs / inserts.

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing this on MYSQL.

It puts all the tables schema and data into their own file so I can easily see what has changed.

Unlike most of the other solutions in this thread this solution gets the data, which is important for a CMS.

This solution doesn't use any tools, just a command line script.

**edit:** I found my older code had a bug where import order was important. taking off the `--compact` flag fixes the bug.

```
for x in `mysql --skip-column-names -u root -ppassword dbname -e 'show tables;'`; do
     echo exporting $x
     mysqldump -u root -ppassword --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks --skip-disable-keys --skip-set-charset --extended-insert=FALSE --replace --skip-dump-date dbname $x > "./db/$x.sql"
done
```

Older code

```
for x in `mysql --skip-column-names -u root -ppassword dbname -e 'show tables;'`; do
     mysqldump -u root -ppassword --compact --extended-insert=FALSE --replace dbname $x > "./db/$x.sql"
done
```

and here is how to import

```
for x in `ls ./db/*.sql`; do
     echo importing $x
     mysql -pdbpassword dbname --force < $x
done
```